# LostWinds - Stuck on Start Screen

Tags: lostwinds

I know this question is very dumb, but I really have no clue. I purchased LostWinds lately for iPhone/iPod Touch. After playing for a few minutes, I wanted to end the game for resuming it later. I tapped the door-button to quit and since them, I think I'm stuck on start screen...

I already tried to play the wind and to tap anything but I really don't know how I can continue the game. Does anybody know what to do now? ^^''

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blow the wind a couple of times on the title character by swiping your fingers across him, eventually he'll wake up.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer! Sadly it didn't work out, no matter what I did :/ Since I'm at the very beginning, I just deleted the game now and installed it again. And now I won't quit the game anymore... I bet the real solution is too simple.